# Typecasting Inversion

Tags: c, casting, logic

I really do not understand why I have to typecast the variable `b` after
inversion (unary `operator ~`). Can anybody explain why this is needed?

```
unsigned char a = 0xFF;
unsigned char b = 0x00; 

return (a == (~b));                //expected to return 1 but 0

...

return (a == (unsigned char)(~b)); //after typecast returns 1 as expected
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Result of `~b` is of promoted type `int` (Generally result of `b` with any other  unary operator `+`, `-` or `~`) so you need to typecast the result.

From C11 spec draft section 6.5.3.3 Unary arithmetic operator:

> The result of the **~ operator** is the bitwise complement of its
>   (**promoted**) operand (that is, each bit in the result is set if and
>   only if the corresponding bit in the converted operand is not set).
>   **The integer promotions are performed on the operand**, and the **result
>   has the promoted type**. If the promoted type is an **unsigned type**, the
>   expression ~E is equivalent to the **maximum value representable in that
>   type minus E**.

So,

```
unsigned char b = 0x00;
/* ~b = 0xFFFFFFFF (assuming 4 byte int), (unsigned char)~b = 0xFF */
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of that!

Comment: I'm glad if it helps you.